# Recommend one good Symplectic topology textbook

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I need to gain some idea of this topic (and holomorphic curves) by the end of next semester. So, if you can, please suggest a textbook or some lecture notes that'll help to build geometric insights.

Comment: Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds has a nice chapter on an introduction to the topic.  In addition to McDuff and Salamon previously mentioned, I believe Da Silva and Da Salva have some "Lecture Notes on Symplectic Geometry" which are quite nice.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mcduff and Salamon "Introduction to Symplectic Topology" is the standard one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion